# How to calculate difference between 2 entries based on dates?

Tags: oracle, date, difference

I have an Oracle DB View like:

```
DATE       | PRODUCT_NUMBER | PRODUCT_COUNT | PRODUCT_FACTOR
2018-01-01 | 1              | 10            | 3
2018-03-15 | 1              | 8             | 3
2019-02-11 | 1              | 11            | 3
2019-08-01 | 1              | 5             | 3
2019-08-01 | 2              | 20            | 5
2019-08-02 | 2              | 15            | 5
2019-06-01 | 2              | 5             | 5
2020-07-01 | 2              | 30            | 5
2018-07-07 | 3              | 100           | 2
```

Where,

- DATE is the date
- NUMBER is a unique Product Number
- COUNT is the number of items from the Product Number in the storage facility
- FACTOR is the number of products that fit into a storage rack

I now need to know how much it changed since the last update for every Product Number.
Since the first entry has no past date to compare to, change is undefined and something like NULL, NONE, 0 or so. Doesn't matter as long as I can filter those out later.

Some products only have 1 entry, those should be ignored (nothing to calculate difference on).

End result should be:

```
DATE       | PRODUCT_NUMBER | PRODUCT_COUNT | PRODUCT_FACTOR | PRODUCT_CHANGE | CHANGE_FACTOR
2018-01-01 | 1              | 10            | 3              | NULL           | NULL
2018-03-15 | 1              | 8             | 3              | 2   # 10-8     | 6  # 2*3
2019-02-11 | 1              | 11            | 3              | -3  # 8-11     | -9 # 3*-3
2019-08-01 | 1              | 5             | 3              | 6   # 11-5     | 18 # 6*3
2019-08-01 | 2              | 20            | 5              | -15 # 5-20     | -75 # -15*5
2019-08-02 | 2              | 15            | 5              | 5   # 20-15    | 25 # 5*5
2019-06-01 | 2              | 5             | 5              | NULL           | NULL
2020-07-01 | 2              | 30            | 5              | -15 # 15-30    | -75 # -15*5
```

How can I achieve this within Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 1):

End result is a bit unclear:

- Why for product_number 2 15 and 5 values are compared - 2019-06-01 is less than 2019-08-01 and should be first row
- Why change_factor for product 1 on the first row is 3 and for product 2 it's null
- Why change_factor for 2019-02-11 is calculated as 11 * 0 instead of 0 * 3

Assumming all of this as typos(changed 2019-06-01 to 2019-09-01) you can use something like below

```
select dt, product_number, product_count, product_factor, product_change, product_change*product_factor change_factor
from (
    select "DATE" dt, product_number, product_count, product_factor,
        greatest(lag(product_count) over(partition by product_number order by "DATE") - product_count, 0) product_change
    from test_tab t1
    where (select count(1) from test_tab t2 where t1.product_number = t2.product_number and rownum < 3) > 1
)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dbd5f86c75cfbfb3874543f2a390df4f)

See also [LAG documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions094.htm#SQLRF00652)

Comment: Yes, those were typos, sorry for that. I (hopefully) fixed those now in the post. Thanks a lot for your answer, sadly I have a View, not a Table so I get "ROWID is invalid for non-material tables".

Comment: You say the opposite thing in the question - "I have an Oracle DB **table**".
Anyway, it's not so important - this "exists" is just to exclude the products with only one row, so you can use any other way, e.g. one in the edited answer.

Also in your current question expected result contains negative product_change values and it doesn't match with "If the new value from the next date is greater than the last entry difference should be 0"